# Accessing helpers and models from rails engine initializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-engines

I'm trying to make a Ruby on Rails engine, and I want the initializer to be able to have access to the helpers and models.
I'll write below an example, part of the code, and the error that I have. It may not be the recommended way, because I can see that in some cases I'm repeating myself, but it's the first engine I make.

file **lib/my_engine/engine.rb**

```rb
module MyEngine
  require 'my_engine/functions'

  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    isolate_namespace MyEngine
    config.autoload_paths += %W( #{config.root}/lib )
  end

  class GlobalVars
    attr_accessor :foo
    def initialize
      @foo = MyEngine::Functions.new
    end
  end

  class << self
    mattr_accessor :GLOBAL
    mattr_accessor :USER_CONFIG

    self.GLOBAL = MyEngine::GlobalVars.new
    # add default values of more config vars here
    self.USER_CONFIG = 'default config'
  end

  def self.setup(&block)
    yield self
  end

end
```

file **lib/my_engine/functions.rb**

```rb
module MyEngine
  require '../../app/helpers/my_engine/options_helper'

  class Functions
    include MyEngine::OptionsHelper

    attr_accessor :some_link

    def initialize
      @some_link = get_option('dummy')
    end
  end
end
```

There is also a controller named `OptionsController` in **app/controllers/my_engine**, and `OptionsHelper` in **app/helpers/my_engine/options_helper.rb**:

```rb
module MyEngine
  module OptionsHelper
    def get_option(name)
      MyEngine::Option.new
    end
  end
end
```

When I try to run the dummy application, this error occurs:

```
/app/helpers/my_engine/options_helper.rb:4:in `get_option': uninitialized constant MyEngine::Option (NameError)
```

If I change to just `Option.new`, I have this error:

```
/app/helpers/my_engine/options_helper.rb:4:in `get_option': uninitialized constant MyEngine::OptionsHelper::Option (NameError)
```

For `::MyEngine::Option.new`, I have:

```
/app/helpers/my_engine/options_helper.rb:4:in `get_option': uninitialized constant MyEngine::Option (NameError)
```

For `::Option.new`, I have:

```
/app/helpers/my_engine/options_helper.rb:4:in `get_option': uninitialized constant Option (NameError)
```

The dummy application has nothing in it. All helpers and models defined above are in the engine.

Before this, I had other errors because it couldn't access the helper, or the `Functions` class. I had to add require and include to make it work even if they are placed in the same directory. Also, to work, I had to move `GlobalVars` from its own file inside engine.rb.

Can somebody show me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: There is a lot less messy way to do [module configuration](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/mygem-configure-block). If you then want to be able to do `MyEngine.foo` instead of `MyEngine.configuration.foo` then just use delegation.

Comment: Can you show how and where `MyEngine::Option` is defined? I am guessing rails is unable to guess the correct path to autoload it?

Comment: @nathanvda, it is in `app/models/my_engine/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After I used required for every class, I ended with `ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished`, and it seems that not everything is loaded and available at that point when the `GLOBAL` object is created.

So I moved the code that was using the models in a separate `init` method. Then, I added an after initialize event:

```rb
  config.after_initialize do
    MyEngine.GLOBAL.init
  end
```

Comment: Ha I think this makes sense: the load-order of rails is something like: the initializers, the engine's initializers, and only then the rest is started .. This allows the initializers a.o. to inject code/behaviour. Good find!

Answer (score 0):

I see a possible problem: because you are inside module `MyEngine` it might be possible that actually rails is looking for `MyEngine::MyEngine::Option`, so I see two approaches:

- just write `Option`: this will look for `MyEngine::Option`
- write `::MyEngine::Option` this will look in the global namespace and find `MyEngine::Option`

Secondly, if that does not help, even though your path seems correct, but you can always explicitly `require "my_engine/option"` at the top of the file. I am not entirely sure the autoloading in an engine works in quite the same way, and I tend to, in my `engine` file, require almost everything (to make sure it works).

Comment: I updated the question with the errors I have using different variants. Also, I am unable to make `require` to work. There will be many models in my engine, and also, many helpers, so I would like to make all of them available **in the initializer**. Otherwise, it works. But I need to do initialize some objects using a lot of helpers in the initializer

Comment: So adding the `require "my_engine/option"` to the top of `my_engine/options_helper.rb` does not work? Does it give an error?

Comment: options_helper.rb:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- my_engine/option (LoadError)

Answer (score 0):

In my `engine.rb` I do

`require_relative '../../app/models/my_engine/option'`

maybe this will help, but it is not a nice solution.

Comment: With this line `require_relative '../../models/my_engine/option'` the error is now at the Option class: `option.rb:2:in <module:MyEngine>: uninitialized constant MyEngine::ApplicationRecord (NameError)`

Comment: But When I run the application without creating the instance for `GLOBAL` in the initializer, everything works without having to write `require` everywhere, just like a normal application. It must be something with loading the classes for an engine.